# ANTLR4 Golang grammar file

Tags: go, antlr4

I'm getting a warning while trying to create AST tree from golang code
**line 6:1 no viable alternative at input 'sMap, lMap map[int32]string\r\n\tif'**
The code I tried,

```
package dum
func mergeIntStrMap(map1 map[int32]string, map2 map[int32]string) string {

    var sMap, lMap map[int32]string
    return lMap
}
```

Grammar file I downloaded from [github]https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/golang/. Is there any issue in the grammar file or any fix for this.
Used code to generate AST(python code),

```
from antlr4 import *
from GoParser import GoParser
from GoLexer import GoLexer
file = FileStream(f,encoding = 'utf-8')
lexer = GoLexer(file)
token = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parse = GoParser(token)
trees = parse.sourceFile()
```

here GoParser and GoLexer files are generated from grammar file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you running the generated parser? Please edit your question and include the code for others to be able to reproduce the error you mention.

Comment: Yes I added snippet to generate that error.

Comment: The grammar has target specific code for C#, Java or Go. Yet you're using Python. How did you handle `superClass = GoParserBase;`? Did you write your own `GoParserBase.py`?

Comment: Yes I wrote for python using java code they provide

Comment: I haven't done the port yet, but the code is easy (GoParserBase.py: `from antlr4 import *
class GoParserBase(Parser):
    def closingBracket(self) -> bool:
        la = self._input.LA(1)
        return la == self.R_PAREN or la == self.R_CURLY
`). You'll have to patch the grammar so that it calls "self.closingBracket()". Parses your example just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You either changed something in the grammar file(s), or you did not implement `GoParserBase.py` correctly, because without changing anything, your example Go code is correctly parsed:

[image]

From the comments, @kaby76 mentions this:

> I haven't done the port yet, but the code is easy `GoParserBase.py`:
>
> ```py
> from antlr4 import * 
>
> class GoParserBase(Parser):
>     def closingBracket(self) -> bool:
>         la = self._input.LA(1)
>         return la == self.R_PAREN or la == self.R_CURLY
> ```
>
> You'll have to patch the grammar so that it calls `self.closingBracket()`.
>
> Parses your example just fine.